# Stuck terminal when creating new flutter project with get_cli?

Tags: flutter, dart, get, get-cli

[image: Creating new project with get_ci]

**Here the activation command**

```
flutter pub global activate get_cli
```

**Here the create new project command**

```
get create project:getcli_test
```

Answer (score 4):

maybe it's too late

it's my solution

after com.yourcompany,

CTRL + Z and enter to continue

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. What will CTRL+Z do?

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands

1.flutter pub global deactivate get

2.flutter pub global deactivate getx

3.dart pub global activate get_cli ^1.6.0

Answer (score 1):

create project manually over flutter by using `create project`

after finished, open terminal and write `get init`
and

wait a moment
and your project now already configured with get cli